# TFS Commandline Help : Deny CheckIn for a branch

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I'm trying to find tf.exe command to deny checkin permission for a branch.

I do this manually by Right Clicking the branch -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Select the Group "[mytfs]\Contributers" and selecting Deny "Check In" checkbox.

After a build is successful, I perform the same stepts to allow "Check In".

As far as I can go with the command line is

```
tf permission /deny:Checkin /Group:[mytfs]\Contributers $/Mytfs/Myproject
```

But I get the error complaining "There is no working folder mapping for blah blah balh..

Could someone please help me out if I'm doing something wrong or I'm trying to use the wrong command?

TFS Version : 2005

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move to a directory within the TFS mapping for this command to work.

If you have your branch mapped to c:\branch1 then run the command from there and it should work.  The problem is that TFS cant figure out what branch you are under.

Comment: Great! Passed step 1 by changing the directory to the one I like to lock. Now It complains Tf14045: The identity [mytfs]\Contributers is not a recognized identity. But I see the group in the TFS Explorer window.

Comment: @Sanjeev cool. Dont be afraid to click "accept" on my answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, Just did :) Thank you!